# How do I give permission to a photographer, to sell images of me, on Stock Photography websites such as Alamy or Shutterstock?

Tags: selling, stock-photography, model-releases, permission, micro-stock

Do I need to give permission in writing to a photographer to sell photos of me on Stock Photography websites like Alamy.

Let's assume that person is a trusted family member. Is letting them know it's okay enough?
If I must give permission in writing to that person, how should I do it?

Comment: When you say "my photos", is that photos you took as the photographer or photos where you are the subject?

Answer (score 2):

When a photographer uploads to stock agencies such as Alamy or Shutterstock, they have 2 options to consider.

**Option 1 - Commercial** - If the image being uploaded is intended to be used for commercial reasons, to be monetised, sell, promote or advertise a product, then for these reasons, the photographer/contributor needs to have a model release form completed by the model.

this link from Alamy is what is required for the model to complete. https://www.alamy.com/contributors/alamy-model-release-form.pdf

**Option 2 - Editorial** - These are images that will not be used for any of the above and and only used for illustrated news articles so no logos are required to be removed and models do not need to complete a model release form or even be made aware that their image is being uploaded.

If the photographer/stock photo contributor is using a model even if that model happens to be the photographer him or herself and the image serves no news worthy purpose but can only really be used for commercial reasons, then a model release form needs to be completed by him or her, even if its a selfie.

Each Stock photography website has its own forms to be completed without which, the photos will not be accepted as commercial images.

Therefore, just giving the photographer verbal or written permission is not enough to be a contributor, these forms need to be completed and uploaded to the respected site.

Answer (score 0):

If a photo is for sale, then yes a modelling release is wise - and many websites will require it.   The purpose of a release is to define who owns the image and limit the compensation you receive for it.   As a model, you might ask yourself - if the photo made the photographer a lot of money, would you be happy with your compensation?   (This NEEDS to be negotiated before the shoot though!)

Here's my "short form" version, hope it helps.   I've used the term "media" rather than "photographs" because sometimes we capture a short video during the shoot as well.

> I hereby give (PHOTOGRAPHER) and their authorized agents permission to use all media created of me on this day for any purpose, in any format, without further compensation.  I acknowledge that media created under this agreement is owned by (PHOTOGRAPHER) and may appear under their brand name (PHOTOGRAPHER COMPANY NAME).
> I am of the age of majority OR I am the legal guardian of any children named below, and I am legally allowed to sign this document.

Then provide your name and contact info, date of the shoot, details of any compensation offered (say if they gave you downloads or some prints or a modelling fee) and sign it.   Easy!